# Should I use references members in this case?

Tags: c++, class, reference, smart-pointers

I'm a student in Computer Science and I'm learning C++ by myself and trying to write a clean C++ program.

Here's my problem:
I'm writing an App class that will be the main class of the program, and I'd like that a lot of my classes could access the App object that will be created in the main function.

Basically the main function will look like that

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   App myApp;

   return myApp.run();
}
```

The App class will have many objects from classes **that needs a reference** (or is something else better in this case ?) to the app.
Here's an example of a class that needs it

```
class AppStateHandler{
private:
    /// < Reference to the App
    App& m_app;
public:
    AppStateHandler(); // How can I initialize m_app with that ??

    /// @param app The app the AppStateHandler will work with
    AppStateHandler(App &app);
};
```

Here are my questions, is it bad to use references as class member in this case ? Should I use some kinds of smart pointers ?
In case of using references, I can't make a **default constructor** because **m_app have to be initialized** in the constructor initialization list so, is it bad to don't have default constructor ?

If you have any advice on how to improve my code I'm interested.

Thank you very much !

**EDIT: I actually want to make an AppStateHandler as a member of App. The only object declared in the main function is the App.**

Comment: I would suggest using smart pointers if there is a possibility that a class could not be linked to an app.

Comment: I personally prefer objects to store pointers as members instead of references, as it allows them to be reassigned later.

Comment: "I'd like that a lot of my classes could access the App object" -- This is generally a bad idea.  Just like use of global variables, it leads to spaghetti design.

Comment: I agree, but all of my AppStates will have a render() procedure, which have to draw things on an SFML Window that belongs to the app, so I'll need to call something like m_app->getWindow().draw(thingToDraw); I took example from some Game Engine examples using SFML and this design seems really common even if it's probably not good, I'm looking for another design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as mentioned in the comments, you should really think about whether you want to pass a reference to your app object to every member object (I'm using the term reference here for anything, that references to another object, be it a raw/smart pointer or an actual reference). The result would be that any function call in your program could potentially alter any other state in your Program. If your objects need a reference to a window to draw something, then just give them a reference to the window and nothing else.

Next, you should NOT use smart pointers here, for two reasons: most smart pointers (e.g. `std::unique_ptr` an `std::shared_ptr`) represent an owning relationship. A reference to a parent object however is just the opposite. Second, as far as I understand the design of your program, the lifetime of your main app object will - by design - exceed the lifetime of any other object in your program anyway, so you don't have to worry about lifetime issues.

Then there is the question about pointer vs reference: In general, as the lifetime of your app will exceed the lifetime of any other object, there is no harm in using a reference (except if you need the ability to default construct your object). 
As far as "good" software design is concerned, you should ask yourself for every class, whether that class has meaning, without the reference to the main app. If it doesn't, use a reference. If it does, use a pointer which you always check against `nullptr` before using it.

Finally: If you have determined, that most of your objects really require that reference and your program logic is such, that there can only be one App, then you might consider implementing it as a singleton. Although I'm not a big fan of them, they are not much worse, than passing a reference to each single object in your program. On the other hand, they can sometimes simplyfy your code, when some objects only hold the reference to "pass it on" but don't use it on their own.

Comment: Thank you very much for those informations, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Using a reference in this case means that the app can't be NULL. But only use references if it's guaranteed that the lifetime of the object is always within the lifetime of the parent. If not, use a smart pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Not using default constructor is not bad at all.

I don't think this is a "reference VS pointer" question. It looks more like lifetime and ownership management of objects.

There are ways to make sure the referrer is within the life time of the referee.

In your case, you are constructing both of them in `main()`'s stack, which is correct. Or you can make `AppStateHandler` a member of `App`, depending on the purpose of your design.

Something to note is that, as `AppStateHandler` grows, it will have a lot of member classes/objects, methods, each of which only does a small amount of job and really don't need access to the whole `App`. Passing the whole `App` to each and every of them will soon make your code nasty.

So, again, depending on the purpose of your design, whichever you choose, pointer or reference, don't pass in too much.

P.S. I believe using shared_ptr/unique_ptr to manage lifetime/ownership across scopes indicates a poor design. 99% of the time you can avoid the necessity of ownership transfer by other design techniques like RAII. Smart pointer is for the other 1% when it's absolute necessary.

Comment: Oh, I misspoke, I meant that AppStateHandler is precisely a member of App.

Comment: Sorry, but some of your statements don't make much sense to me. Smart pointers e.g. are a form of RAII. The ressource is the object that is created of the heap and it is used to initialize a smart pointer. If you meant that shared_ptr gets overused, then we agree often, one can use a unique_ptr  or even a raw pointer instead. Also the rule of three has nothng to do with having a default constructor. It is about needing a destructor, copy assignment and copy constructor (and since c++11 their respective move versions).

Comment: @MikeMB Edited. But RAII requires constructor-allocate and destructor-deallocate. Smart pointers doesn't fit that description as resources are already allocated before constructor is called.

Comment: Well, first of all, the recommendet way is to use `std::make_shared` or `std::make_unique` anyway, which does exactly what you say. Second I'd not say that the allocation MUST happen inside the constructor - its just the typical way to do it (CADRe). RAII is a concept, that can be realized in different ways. The important thing is that when a ressource (or rather a responsibility) is aquired (doesn't matter whether it is Memory, a file, a mutex etc.) it is used to initialize a handle with takes care of its release and smart pointers can be used just for just that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use references, you could even use smart pointers (though there is little point in doing so), but your problem screams for another solution: a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

To use the singleton pattern, you would add a single static method to your `App` class, which has the only responsibility to return a reference to the one and only `App` object. The constructor of `App` should be private, so that other code cannot generate a second `App` object. The implementation would look something like this:

```
class App {
    private:
        App();
        App(App const&) = delete;

    public:
        static App& getApp() {
            static App theApp;
            return theApp;
        }
}
```

That way all other objects can reference the `App` object by simply calling `App::getApp()`.

Comment: Yeah, I was also thinking of using this pattern